# Using PROC FORMAT and PROC FCMP to convert values in SAS

Tags: sas, format, fcmp

I nedd to write a `PROC FORMAT` and `PROC FCMP`in my SAS programm to convert values in horsepower to watts. Watts should have the following format: `XXXXX,XX Watt.`

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.functions.fun;
    function hptow(c) $;
        n = cats(c*745.7, ' Watts');
        return (n);
    endsub;
run;

options cmplib=work.functions;

proc format;
    value hptow other=[hptow()];
    run;

data my_cars;
    set sashelp.cars; 
    format horsepower hptow.;
run;
```

But results look something like that:

```
197610.
201339W
```

How do i change this mistake and have needed output format for formated column?

Comment: Try setting the length of the format. The default is 8 characters and looks like your formats will be longer. `value hptow (default=20) other = [hptow()];`

Comment: https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=p1upn25lbfo6mkn1wncu4dyh9q91.htm&locale=en

Comment: Are you using comma as the decimal separator?

Comment: What is your system localization (in Windows it's found under Region Settings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a LENGTH for the variable you are calculating in the function.  If you want the space in front of the W then don't remove it by using the CATS() function.

```
length n $14;
n = put(c*745.7,commax8.2) || ' Watts' ;
```

Set a default width for the format.

```
value hptow (default=14) other=[hptow()];
```

But why not just use a PICTURE format?

```
proc format ;
picture hptow 
 low-high = '00009,99 Watt' (mult=74570) 
;
run;
```

Results:

```
410   data test;
411     do hp=1,2,5,12 ;
412       w=hp*745.7 ;
413       put hp= w= @20 hp hptow.;
414     end;
415   run;

hp=1 w=745.7         745,70 Watt
hp=2 w=1491.4       1491,40 Watt
hp=5 w=3728.5       3728,50 Watt
hp=12 w=8948.4      8948,40 Watt
```

Comment: Also probably worth noting that the `CATS` is removing that space between the number and " Watts" - you fix it in your code, but might be worth explicitly mentioning.